# Segment intersection between 2 non convex polygons with small amount of edges faster than Trapezoid Sweep Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, geometry, intersection

Recently I've made some research as I needed to find efficient way of calculating whether 2 convex or concave polygons intersect. I don't need all intersection points but the first one between segments from 2 different figures.

In my case one polygon won't have more than 4 edges but the second has approximately ~20 edges. I am quite fresh in this area and would like to ask if there's more efficient approach to solving such a problem than O(n log(n) + k) trapezoid sweep algorithm?

In case one polygon has 4 edges and the other has 20 edges the simple brute force approach would need pessimistically 4*20 = 80 checks between 2 segments.

Becouse the first polygon has only 4 edges the trapezoid sweep seems to be slower: O(24 log(24) + k) > 110. Does this mean that I should use the brute force approach or there exists some better solution to this or maybe the sweep algorithm would perform better in practice?

Comment: Yes, brute force is probably the best choice here.

Comment: Do we need to mention a bounding box test for quick rejection of non-intersecting polygons ? (You can also think of testing intersection of the convex hulls with a fast convex-polygon test, but the benefit will probably be marginal - if not negative - after bounding box rejection.)

Comment: yeah I'm doing bounding box test. One optimization that I thought to the brute force approach would be to sort the points separately for each polygon by the X coordinate. Then I would iterate over points of 1 polygon and check intersection with edges of second polygon only with those edges that their x coordinate is not smaller / bigger than x in first polygon's current segment.